# Ordering balls in a line. probability of the event $\{\text{ no ball in the first 4 balls is blue }\}$

Tags: probability

given $8$ red balls, $5$ blue balls, $9$ green balls. assume all the ordering options have the equal probability. what is the probability of the event $$\{\text{ no ball in the first 4 balls is blue }\}$$

**My attempt:**

My probability space is $$\Omega = \binom{17}{4}$$ this is because I have to choose 4 balls without the $5$ blues. But I am not sure if this is true because it can be treated "choose 4 balls without 5 reds".

In addition to that, I need to determine the power of my event group wich is pretty hard for me to understand how should I do it.

I hope some one can help

Comment: What you have calculated is not your sample space, but your event, namely choosing four balls from the $22 - 5 = 17$ balls which are not blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:** We find the probability that none of the first four balls selected are blue.

There are $8 + 5 + 9 = 22$ balls.  You can select four of them in
$$\binom{22}{4}$$
ways.  Of these $22$ balls, $22 - 5 = 17$ are not blue.  Thus, the number of ways you can select four balls so that none of them are blue is
$$\binom{17}{4}$$
Therefore, the probability that no ball in the first four balls is blue is
$$\frac{\dbinom{17}{4}}{\dbinom{22}{4}}$$

**Method 2:**  We calculate the probability that there are no blue balls in the first four positions of an arrangement of the balls in a line.

If we instead took our sample space to be all possible arrangements of $8$ red, $5$ blue, and $9$ green balls, we would have to choose $8$ positions for the red balls, $5$ of the remaining $14$ positions for the blue balls, and all $9$ of the remaining positions for the green balls, giving
$$\binom{22}{8}\binom{14}{5} = \frac{22!}{8!14!} \cdot \frac{14!}{5!9!} = \frac{22!}{8!5!9!}$$
possible arrangements, where the factors in the bottom represent, respectively, the number of ways we could permute the eight red balls among themselves, the five blue balls among themselves, and nine green balls among themselves since permuting balls of the same color among does not produce an arrangement distinguishable from the given arrangement.

As for the favorable cases, we must choose five of the last $22 - 4 = 18$ positions for the blue balls since none of them can appear in the first four positions.  Once we have done so, we must choose which eight of the remaining $222 - 5 = 17$ positions will be filled with red balls.  All of the remaining nine positions must be filled with green balls.  Hence, the number of favorable cases is
$$\binom{18}{5}\binom{17}{8}$$
Thus, the desired probability is
$$\frac{\dbinom{18}{5}\dbinom{17}{8}}{\dbinom{22}{8}\dbinom{14}{5}}$$

As you can verify, the two methods yield the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your space of events $\Omega$ is the set of all essentially unique orders. By "essentially unique" I mean that, if two balls of the same colour are switched, the element of the set $\Omega$ which identifies the new sequence doesn't change. The size of this set is
\begin{equation}
\#\Omega=\frac{22!}{8!\cdot 5!\cdot 9!}.
\end{equation}
This is because, once a permutation of the $22$ balls is fixed, you're allowed to re-arrange them as long as you don't switch two balls of two different colours. The event $E$ you're interested in is that none of the first four balls is blue, therefore the $5$ blue balls must appear in the last $18$ ones. How many are the ways in which I can choose a subset of $5$ elements in a set of $18$ elements? This number is given by
\begin{equation}
a=\binom{18}{5}.
\end{equation}
Once you have fixed the position of the five blue balls, every disposition of the remaining $17$ balls is allowed, and there are exactly
\begin{equation}
b=\frac{17!}{8!\cdot 9!}
\end{equation}
of these dispositions. Therefore $\#E=a\cdot b$ and computing $\#E/\#\Omega$ gives the solution to your problem.

Comment: I agree with the methods described in your answer, but if you look carefully mine is also correct and delivers the same answer.

Comment: Sorry, I read your answer too quickly.  It is indeed correct.